# Using PM2 with sails trigger a grunt error

Tags: heroku, sails.js, pm2

I'm using sails on Heroku and I would like to optimize concurrency on 2X dynos by using pm2 to have 2 process running per dyno.

However I'm facing a quite annoying problem as when I start the app with pm2 start app.js, the first process run fine but the second one trigger a grunt error : 

`Aborted due to warnings.
2015-09-14T10:41:41.897208+00:00 app[web.3]: Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
2015-09-14T10:41:41.897209+00:00 app[web.3]: Cleaning .tmp/public...ERROR
2015-09-14T10:41:41.897211+00:00 app[web.3]: Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp/public" file (ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty '.tmp/public/images').`

Does anyone encountered this problem ? It's quite annoying as for the moment I pay a 2X dyno to use only one processor...

Thank you

Comment: I suppose that Sails is trying to clean and copy files again on second start. But these files is already used by first instance. Solution ? I don't know about your issue, but I'm splitting REST API based on Sails and frontend written with React, for instance. So I'm scaling only REST API instances and never faced the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be achieve by running multiple instance at single folder because Sails will modify, concat, minify, etc. files at `assets` folder and place it to `.tmp` folder. So if you do run multimple instance, grunt process will conflict. If you still want to do it, achieve by running on multiple folders, copy paste your project folder to any other folder.